# Find the value of $x >0$ for which the series is converges

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find the value of $x >0$ for which the series

$1 + \frac{x}{1!} + \frac {2^2x^2} {2!}  + \frac {3^3x^3}{ 3!} +....+ \frac {n^nx^n} {n!}$+......................... converges

My solution :  By D - Alembert 's Ratio Test ,the series  will converges if $x < \frac {1}{e} $ and diverges if  $x> \frac {1}{e}$

Is  Its  true/false  ??..Pliz  check my answer

thanks in advance

Comment: what if $x=1/e$?

Comment: @Lord shark it will  be Diverge

Comment: Do you want to know if it's true or false? Or you want to know how to use D'Alemberts to check if it's true or false?

Comment: @AdriánHinojosaCalleja  i  want to  know  wheather my  answer is true/false..

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown at x= 1/e   ratio test  will fail......soory  that  was  my mistake .....i now  im sure  that  my answer is correct

Comment: It would will be nice if you write the procedure that make you conclude that is true or false (write the computation you did using D'Alemberts on your question :P)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$1 + \frac{x}{1!} + \frac {2^2x^2} {2!}  + \frac {3^3x^3}{ 3!} +....+ \frac {n^nx^n} {n!}$$

Root test gives $$ \frac {nx}{n!^{1/n}} \to ex $$

Thus it converges for $|x|<1/e$

Comment: thank you for your attention and understanding. This was indeed a good question.